# Regular expression - number between 2 strings in a URL

Tags: regex

I need Your help with RE:

My source text is: `tpl?nik=8942467302&regan=`

I want select only this number: `8942467302`

I'm using the regex `/(?<=nik=)(.*)&(?=regan)/`, which selects`8942467302&`

I don't want the "&" at the end of the match.  How can I get the number without the trailing "&"?

Comment: Make the `.*` ungreedy `.*?` or use something like this `/(?<=nik=)([^&]*)(?=&regan)/`

Comment: What regex platform/tool you're using?

Comment: Moving the `&` inside the lookahead will exclude it from the overall match because you aren't consuming anything after it, but still retain the criteria.

Comment: Try to give more details when you ask for a regex pattern. If all you want is to extract the number from _that exact_ string, `\d+` is sufficient, but judging from your regex pattern, that's not what you want. When it comes to building a regex pattern, we need to know _as much as possible_ about what the pattern is going to be used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your regex looks good.
If you are sure the nik is only digits you can use this:

```
(?<=nik=)(\d{1,})&(?=regan)
```

You can use this online tool to test your regex:
http://regex101.com/
Just copy the regex at the top and put your test string below.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
(\d+)
```

No borders, `+` is greedy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'tpl?nik=8942467302&regan=' | egrep -o '[[:digit:]]+' 
8942467302
```

Answer (score 0):

## Move the "&" to the lookahead group:

By moving the & to the lookahead group, you will cause it to be excluded from the match:

```
s = 'tpl?nik=8942467302&regan=
s[/(?<=nik=)(.*)(?=&regan)/]    # => "8942467302"
```

## Extract only the group you want, rather than the entire match.

Using String#[] as we did above returns the entire match.  By giving it a group number, you can make it return only the group you are interested in.  So, using your original regular expression:

```
s = 'tpl?nik=8942467302&regan='
s[/(?<=nik=)(.*)&(?=regan)/, 1]    # => "8942467302"
```

## Use a URI parsing library

Since you are extracting values from a URI, you can use Ruby's standard libraries to extract the parameter you want:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'uri'

s = 'tpl?nik=8942467302&regan='
query = URI(s).query          # => "nik=8942467302&regan="
params = CGI::parse(query)    # => {"nik"=>["8942467302"], "regan"=>[""]}
nik = params["nik"].first     # => "8942467302"
```

I recommend doing this.  It's a few more lines of code, but at a higher level of abstraction.  You free your code from the details of how to parse URI parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for Help!
I use this code: `/(?<=nik=)([^&]*)(?=&regan)/`